# PHPIniDir Directive causing apache to crash

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache (httpd-2.2.17-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8o) and PHP (php-5.3.5-Win32-VC9-x86) on Windows XP SP3 and when i use put the PHPIniDir into the Apache configuration file, then Apache won't start, it would crash, and if i removed the directive it works fine but of course doesn't read the PHP configuration.
What might be causing this and what should i do to fix it ?

Here is how it appears inside httpd.conf

```
#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
LoadModule php5_module "D:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir "D:/Program Files/PHP/"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .html
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
```

Comment: Well, what does apache's error log say?

Comment: [Wed Jul 04 23:39:48 2012] [warn] pid file D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Answer (score 1):

based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2947927)

Open php.ini file with a notepad or any text editor. Disable all of the extension in php.ini file. Comment extensions by one by, and find out which extension causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong PHP version.
Use VC6 instead of VC9 (at least for this apache version)

Comment: Well this is an old question of mine, back then I was learning PHP, but I left PHP now and can't test your answer. If I used PHP in the future I will test your answer and give you the credit you deserve.